# Implicit Differentiation - Logarithm

Tags: implicit-differentiation

> $x\log(x) + y\log(y) = 1$
>
> $\dfrac{dy}{dx}= ?$

I calculated $\frac{dy}{dx}= -\frac{1+\log(x)}{1+\log(y)}$

however, the correct answer seems to be $-\log(x)/\log(y)$

I'm confused, can someone help?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Could you please explain how you achieved your solution?

Comment: Your solution is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I got $$\log(x)+1+y'\log(y)+y'=0$$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that $\log(x)=\log_e(x)=\ln(x)$, we start off with our equation:

$$x\log(x)+y\log(y)=1$$

Next we perform implicit differentiation to both sides:

$$
\frac{dy}{dx}(x\log(x)+y\log(y))=\frac{dy}{dx}(1)\\
1+\log(x)+\frac{dy}{dx}1+\frac{dy}{dx}\log(y)=0
$$

Now we isolate $\frac{dy}{dx}$ to one side:

$$
1+\log(x)+\frac{dy}{dx}1+\frac{dy}{dx}\log(y)=0\\
\frac{dy}{dx}1+\frac{dy}{dx}\log(y)=-\log(x)-1\\
\frac{dy}{dx}(1+\log(y))=-\log(x)-1\\
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-\log(x)-1}{1+\log(y)}\\
$$

Finally we clean things up and simplify:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{dx}&=\frac{-\log(x)-1}{1+\log(y)}\\
&\bbox[5px,border:2px solid black]
{=-\frac{1+\log(x)}{1+\log(y)}
}
\end{align}$$

We see that your solution is indeed correct.